# List of ways to reference the redux store `dispatch` method?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

What is the list of ways to reference the redux store `dispatch` method ?

- Use `connect` from github.com/reduxjs/react-redux ([docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options))
- Use the react-redux `<Provider />` ([docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store)).
- Use the new context api.  [(New context api introduced in React 16.3)](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#official-context-api)
- Declare a global `dispatch` variable and set it to `store.dispatch`.
- Pass store.dispatch as a prop to child components.
- Export `store.dispatch` from one module, then use `es6 import` to reference it from another module. ( example below )
- Are there others ?

es6 import Example :

```
// store.js
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ITEM_UPDATED":
      return Object.assign({}, state, { item: action.item });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer, { item: "cat" });

export default store;   // <-------- export the store

// DumbComponent.js
import store from "./store.js"; // <-------- import the store

const DumbComponent = props => {
  return React.createElement(
    "button",
    {
      onClick: () => {
        store.dispatch({ type: "ITEM_UPDATED", item: "dog" }); <-- call dispatch
      }
    },
    "Update to Dog"
  );
};
```

My preference is to use the es6 `import` method for dumb components, because it has the least amount of boilerplate, was also wondering if there are any issues specific to using es6 import that the other methods listed above would not encounter.

Comment: Use https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux. You can then connect any arbitrary component to the Store, which gives you access to both `state` and `dispatch`

Comment: thanks I added `connect` to the list.